# Specify text color whenever I write a particular word in JTextPane

Tags: java, jtextarea, text-editor, jtextpane

Is there a way to specify the color I want text to have when I write it? Let's say I set "Apple" to the color red. If I write "this Apple is good Apple" in a JTextPane, the word "apple" should turn red.

Here is what I have so far, but it just shows all black.  I would like to make the words `Apple` show up in red

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    //Would like to make the words Apple Red in foreground color
    textPane.setText("this Apple is good Apple");


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a map of words to colors.  As you can see, I mapped `apple` to red and the word `green` to the color green

```
public class Test {

    HashMap<String, Color> myMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        myMap.put("apple", Color.RED);
        myMap.put("apples", Color.RED);
        myMap.put("green", Color.GREEN);
        String text = "This is a green apple and  I like to eat Apples";

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();



        Style style = textPane.addStyle("Red Style", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);
        ArrayList<Chunk> chunks = getColorsBasedOnText(text, textPane);
        try {
            for (Chunk chunk : chunks) {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), chunk.text + " ", chunk.style);
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ArrayList<Chunk> getColorsBasedOnText(String text, JTextPane textPane) {
        ArrayList<Chunk> chunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        for (String word: text.split(" ")) {
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
            chunk.text = word;
            Color color =  myMap.get(word.toLowerCase());
            if (color != null) {
                chunk.style = textPane.addStyle("Style", null);
                StyleConstants.setForeground(chunk.style, color);
            }
            chunks.add(chunk);
        }
        return chunks;
    }

    private class Chunk {
        public String text;
        public Style style;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the color of the words change when i write it in the JTextPane GUI? because after I run the program and write the word "green" again it doesn't change to green color. that is actually what I'm trying to do. Sorry if I'm not explaining it better.

Comment: You should be able to style the JTextPane AFTER you have created it.  This is all at once just to keep the example short and sweet.  You may need to repack the frame...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick pass.  Need to parse the string and set style based on matched values, but here is a start.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

    Style style = textPane.addStyle("Red Style", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);

    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "This ", null);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Apple", style);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " is a good ", null);
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Apple", style);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this will come in handy but I didn't ask the question properly. I'm building a custom text editor that displays certain words in specific color. So whenever someone types any of those words in the text editor, it shows that word in the specified color.

Comment: Ahh, your right, I am a little off from what you said.  This is possible and I did this a while back with a custom required indicator, but I think I had to get into the drawing part.  Will try to find some old code on this, but I think it is not trivial.

Comment: Did the new one help

Comment: This is almost exactly what i need. it displays the right outcome but what i really need is just as you said, to set style based on matched values. that is for the editor to change the color of the word after it has been written in the editor, not words pre-defined in the program.

Comment: Had a version of that started, but I am heading out to dinner...  should not be too bad, just depends on how many different colors and words you are searching for.  Do you have that info

Comment: if i can get two words with two different colors, it'll be perfect

Comment: Take a look at the version below.  Please do not forget to vote on answers and mark it as a solution if it works for you.  That would help ME out.